# Safety/sanitization when storing images in DB with PHP

Tags: sql-server, database, image, codeigniter, sanitization

I'm looking to store images for an application in an MSSQL database. (I understand that there is some debate about whether this or file system storage is better; that's another thread though.) I'm looking at doing something similar to http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/ but in CodeIgniter, something along the lines of:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $upload_name => $info) {
    if ($info['name']) {
        // Temporary file name stored on the server
        $tmpName  = $info['tmp_name'];  

        // Read the file 
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        fclose($fp);

        //model code consolidated here for ease of question-asking
        $db = $this->load->database();
        $stmt = $db->insert('my_table', array('image' => $data));
    }
}
```

My question is mostly along the lines of security. Basically is there any particular concerns I should have for sanitizing image binary data inserts versus other sorts of string data? I took out the addslashes() in the code from the site linked above because I know CI's active records do some sanitization on their own but I don't know if it is better to have it (or do some other prep work altogether).

Comment: Security in what sense? What is an example of something you are afraid of happening? By the way: `addslashes` should not be used to escape parameters in SQL queries, and that is not its purpose. Are you just asking about SQL injection or something else?

Comment: if your data is a blob, and you never manipulate it otherwise, there is no reason to sanitize it. The important question is: how do you use that data when read from storage? Do you store it in a temporary file for the client?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yeah, pretty much just wondering about SQL injection; haven't stored images in a database before so wasn't sure if there were extra concerns.

Comment: @didierc Haven't quite figured that part out yet but the ultimate aim is to be able to dynamically retrieve and display the image to the user when requested. If you have any guidance on this, I will be much obliged. :)

Comment: My guess is that you will have some sort of id tied to the image, and have a temporary disk space to store images in. Whenever a client request an image, it would be first attempted to find it on disk, and if not present run the sql. The disk space behaving like a cache, you will have to define rules as to how space is managed, this is probably the most tricky part, and certainly deserves a SO question on its own.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you should not have to worry about it as long as you store the file_type (The file's Mime type) with it and fore the Mime type with the binary data. Then whenever you handle the data you make sure and use it with the proper Mime type so even if they upload a script of virus you can make sure it is only rendered as an image instead of letting your server or the browser handle it.

Other than this I do not think you will need to pull the upload into memory and try and scrub it.

Comment: keeping track of the mime type is indeed essential. I wonder if discovering the real type of the file (in case of user mistake) would be a good thing.